# How to change SDK version in android project

Tags: android

I have developed an android application with Android Version-4.0.4 and API level 15.
but im not able to test the application in any of the android phones.
So i want to downscale the SDK version.What should i do for that?
Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

check below images it may help you.

[image]

[image]

choose SDK version Press OK.

Comment: This only changes the target SDK version.  It is best to just edit the AndroidManifest file manually.

Comment: this is for new comers. who have not more Exp. in Android Development.

Answer (score 2):

If you view the source code of your AndroidManifest.xml file then you should see the minimum SDK value that can be changed.

For example:

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="16"
        android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In manifest file just write

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

OR

Right click your project and go to properties

Click Android tab

[image]

And from here you can change SDK version

Comment: This is the build target SDK version, not the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

to your manifest, so you can run in Android phone 1.6 and up.
Beware if you use some code that require api > your phone api level, you will get a force close.